# Aren't curly brackets the metacharacters in regular expressions in cygwin?

Tags: regex, cygwin, curly-brackets

I want to search the phone-number in a text file using grep in cygwin.
The number is `0570-2770521`, and I use the regular expression 
"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{7}" with total command as `grep "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{7}" ./list.txt`, but it didn't work. 
Then I changed to `grep "[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{7\}" ./list.txt`, it works!

But since the {} are metacharacters, if escape them, they will be just literal characters, then how can they represent the match times of [0-9]?

Does that I got a wrong understanding?
Hope someone can help to explain the confusion, thanks in advance!

Best regards!

Comment: In bre you need to escape {} whereas in pcre you don't need to escape {} to use them as metachar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man re_format`:

> Obsolete ("basic") regular expressions differ in several respects. [...] The delimiters for bounds are `\{` and `\}`, with `{` and `}` by themselves ordinary characters.

Use `egrep` (or, equivalently, `grep -E`) for enhanced regular expressions, which may be more familiar to you.

Comment: so, {} is ordinary characters in basic regex, but seems [] works in basic regex, why {} is so special and are there any metacharacters also ordinary in basic regex? I have read many materials, they all didn't mention about this.

Comment: Because originally the count modifiers were not a part of regexp, they were added later (unlike character classes, which have been there pretty much forever). So to preserve backwards compatibility, they couldn't suddenly promote `{` and `}` from being ordinary characters to metacharacters, because the older scripts that used them as normal characters would break.